# Calculate classes' percentage with dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I'm kind of stuck here, where it seems that I am missing something. I need to calculate percentages for each class of a legend over a dictionnairy of listed elements. Here is my content:

```
Legend = {u'Conifer': 1.0, u'Hardwood': 4.0, u'Field': 5.0, u'Urban': 6.0, u'Water': 8.0}
PolyItems = {u'5423': [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0],
             u'425': [6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 8.0, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
             u'9756': [1.0, 1.0, 4.0],
             u'6418': [4.0, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0]}
```

Now, I was trying to make a loop over the Legend variable and use a lambda function to calculate the percentages of each class, but I always get `0.0` for each items.

```
nb = lambda v, c: float(len([x for x in v if v==c]))
nbtot = lambda v: float(len(v))
for name, cla in Legend.iteritems():
    result = {id: nb(vals, cla)/nbtot(vals) * 100
                for id, vals in PolyItems.items() if len(id) > 0}
```

Can I use a lambda function for this? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `nb` lambda should be defined as shown:

```
from operator import itemgetter

Legend = {u'Conifer': 1.0, u'Hardwood': 4.0, u'Field': 5.0, u'Urban': 6.0, u'Water': 8.0}
PolyItems = {u'5423': [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0],
             u'425' : [6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 8.0, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0],
             u'9756': [1.0, 1.0, 4.0],
             u'6418': [4.0, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0]}

nb = lambda v, c: v.count(c)
nbtot = lambda v: float(len(v))
longest_name = max(len(name) for name in Legend)

for name, cla in sorted(Legend.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1)):
    result = {id: nb(vals, cla)/nbtot(vals) * 100
                for id, vals in PolyItems.items() if len(id) > 0}
    print('{:<{width}}(class {}): {}'.format(name, cla, result, width=longest_name+1))
```

Output:

```
Conifer  (class 1.0): {u'9756': 66.66666666666666, u'425': 18.181818181818183, u'6418': 50.0, u'5423': 50.0}
Hardwood (class 4.0): {u'9756': 33.33333333333333, u'425': 27.27272727272727, u'6418': 25.0, u'5423': 25.0}
Field    (class 5.0): {u'9756': 0.0, u'425': 0.0, u'6418': 0.0, u'5423': 0.0}
Urban    (class 6.0): {u'9756': 0.0, u'425': 45.45454545454545, u'6418': 0.0, u'5423': 0.0}
Water    (class 8.0): {u'9756': 0.0, u'425': 9.090909090909092, u'6418': 25.0, u'5423': 0.0}
```

**Note:** The two lambda functions aren't really necessary since Python has built-ins that perform those operations. This means the code can be simplified somewhat by omitting them—i.e. the following code will produce exactly the same output:

```
longest_name = max(len(name) for name in Legend)

for name, cla in sorted(Legend.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1)):
    result = {id: vals.count(cla)/float(len(vals)) * 100
                for id, vals in PolyItems.items() if len(id) > 0}
    print('{:<{width}}(class {}): {}'.format(name, cla, result, width=longest_name+1))
```

Comment: I changed  `sum(x for x in v if x==c)/c` for proper calculations.

I am trying to bypass the need of using ArcGIS/ArcPy to calculate the percentage of watersheds coverages. The Legend correspond to the  map's legend. I converted a AsciiGrid to points and then, I identifyed the all the points that falls in the watersheds' polygons and stored them. Then every time I need to update (if the grid is the same size and resolution), I just use this function. This is particulary usefull with weather data that change every hour.

Comment: @orange: Yeah, I got that wrong because I happened to mostly be paying attention to the first case were `c` happens to `1.0`, so both expressions give the same answer. I've corrected that in my answer accordingly and also added a **Note** you might find interesting. If my answer solved or help solve your problem, please consider also up-voting it—thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
nb = ... if v==c]))
```

You are comparing a list `v` against a float value `c` in `nb` which always returns `False` making the function produce `0.0` for any parameters.

I don't know what that function is for but I think it should be defined as:

```
nb = lambda v, c: float(len([x for x in v if x==c]))
```

Comment: I think you're right. Also, float `==` comparison isn't reliable.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hate it when this happens.